# How to add a ball into my maze that I can move?

Tags: java, eclipse, maze

I have a maze and GUI here that seems to have gone wrong, the objective is to make the grid 13 x 16 and to have a ball that can be controlled by either the arrow keys on the keyboard or on the GUI, at this stage it does not matter which.

For some reason my maze hasn't formed very well as you can see here -
[image]

It is supposed to look like this [image]

My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CBallMaze extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
//Below is where I have declared all the different objects I have used throughout my program

private JButton buttonRight, buttonLeft, buttonUp, buttonDown, buttonTL, buttonTR, buttonBL, buttonBR, buttonCenter, optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree, optionExit, scenarioAct, scenarioRun, scenarioReset, compassPH;
private JButton [] game = new JButton [208];
private JPanel panelCentre, panelRight, panelBottom, buttonPanel, compassPanel, optionsPanel, selectionPanel, panelAct, panelRun, panelReset, panelSlider;
private JTextField optionTF, squareTF, directionTF;
private JLabel option, square, direction, compassDirection;
private JSlider speedSlider;
private String firstOption = "1", secondOption = "2", thirdOption = "3", upDirection = "North", rightDirection = "East", downDirection = "South", leftDirection = "West";
private int i;
private int[] map = new int[]
        {
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
        3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,
        3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,
        3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,
        3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,
        3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,
        4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        };
```

and

```
    try
    {
        iconSand = new ImageIcon("sand.jpg");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Sand Icon "+e);
    }

    try
    {
        iconBall = new ImageIcon("sand60x60.png");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Ball Icon "+e);
    }

    try
    {
        iconWhite = new ImageIcon("white32x32.jpg");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("White Icon "+e);
    }

    try
    {
        iconEnd = new ImageIcon("sandstone.jpg");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("End Icon"+e);
    }

    for (i=0;i<208;i++)
    {
        game[i] = new JButton ();

        if(map[i]==1)
        {
            game[i].setIcon(iconSand);
        }
        if(map[i]==2)
        {
            game[i].setIcon(iconBall);
        }
        if(map[i]==3)
        {
            game[i].setIcon(iconWhite);
        }
        if(map[i]==4)
        {
            game[i].setIcon(iconEnd);
        }

        game[i].setBorder(null);
        game[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32, 32));
        game[i].addActionListener(this);
        panelCentre.add(game[i]);
```

thanks for any help!
Here is the code for the panel center:

```
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout() );

    //Panels

    panelCentre = new JPanel();
    panelCentre.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(625, 450));
    panelCentre.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    window.add(panelCentre);
    panelCentre.setLayout(new GridLayout(21, 30));
```

Comment: Looks like your map array controls the layout of the maze, am I right? You have posted lots of code which I think is irrelevant to your problem. Just post the bit where you refer again to the map array. I think that's where the problem lies. It might be easier to use a 2D array, because a maze itself is 2D and then you can refer to coordinates.

Comment: I'm not sure that these lines ... `iconBall = new ImageIcon("sand60x60.png");` make sense? You call it iconBall, but are using an image called sand! You also need to make all your tiles the same size (some appear to be 32x32, other 60x60).

Comment: Your `panelCenter` is not layingout properly. What layout are you using for it? Put the part of code where you specify a layout for `panelCenter` and related code.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Sorry for the confusion, that image is the image for the ball, it just has a silly name. I have just been provided with the image files, I did not create them my self

Comment: @NickJ the code I have posted is the supposed layout for the maze and the try catch code to tell it how to layout the maze with each image :)

Comment: @Codebender I have updated my post with the code you requested :)

Comment: Why have you given a GridLayout size of `21 X 30` when your grid is only `13 X 16`?

Comment: @Codebender Oh, I don't know. Okay I changed that to 13x16 and it fixed the issues with how the maze looks thank you! Now I just need to get the ball to move around the maze :)